# How to create a 1-D range tensor when dimension is Unknown?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computation-graph

I have a n-D array. I need to create a 1-D range tensor based on dimensions.

for an example:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,4]) 
  
r = tf.range(start=0, limit=, delta=x.shape[0],dtype=tf.int32, name='range')

sess = tf.Session()

result = sess.run(r, feed_dict={x: raw_lidar})
print(r)
```

The problem is, x.shape[0] is none at the time of building computational graph. So I can not build the tensor using range. It gives an error.

```
ValueError: Cannot convert an unknown Dimension to a Tensor: ?
```

Any suggestion or help for the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.shape[0]` might not exist yet when running this code is graph mode. If you want a value, you need to use `tf.shape(x)[0]`.

More information about that behaviour in the [documentation for `tf.Tensor.get_shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor?hl=en#get_shape). An excerpt (**emphasis** is mine):

> tf.Tensor.get_shape() is equivalent to tf.Tensor.shape.
>
> **When executing in a tf.function or building a model using tf.keras.Input, Tensor.shape may return a partial shape (including None for unknown dimensions).** See tf.TensorShape for more details.
>
> ```
> >>> inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape = [10])
> >>> # Unknown batch size
> >>> print(inputs.shape)
> (None, 10)
> ```
>
> The shape is computed using shape inference functions that are registered for each tf.Operation.
> The returned tf.TensorShape is determined at build time, without executing the underlying kernel. It is not a tf.Tensor. **If you need a shape tensor, either convert the tf.TensorShape to a tf.constant, or use the tf.shape(tensor) function, which returns the tensor's shape at execution time.**